# How to search M to N relationship in prisma?

Tags: orm, prisma, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma, prisma2

I'm working on project with prisma nowadays.
I designed m to n relationship table. Below is my code.
schema.prisma

```
model Artists {
  id                 Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
  artistName         String?
  Albums             Albums[]
  Artists_Tracks     Artists_Tracks[]
}

model Artists_Tracks {
  id       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  trackId  Int?
  artistId Int?
  Artists  Artists? @relation(fields: [artistId], references: [id])
  Tracks   Tracks?  @relation(fields: [trackId], references: [id])

  @@index([artistId], name: "Artists_Tracks_artistId_foreign_idx")
  @@index([trackId], name: "Artists_Tracks_trackId_foreign_idx")
}

model Tracks {
  id                Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  trackName         String?
  albumTrackNumber  Int?
  albumId           Int?
  Albums            Albums?             @relation(fields: [albumId], references: [id])
  Artists_Tracks    Artists_Tracks[]

  @@index([albumId], name: "Tracks_albumId_foreign_idx")
}
```

This is my prisma code. What I want to do is search by trackname and get all tracks's information with artist's name.

+edit)
What I've tried is

```
// first try
optObj.include = {
    Albums: {
      select: { cover: true },
    },
    Artists_Tracks: {
       Albums: true
    },
 };

// second try
optObj.include = {
    Albums: {
      select: { cover: true },
    },
    Artists_Tracks: true,
    Artists: true,
  };


  const result = await prisma.tracks.findMany(optObj);
```

and use promise.all to get artist's name for each track. Is there any way to do that in once by one query? I'm pretty sure there would be more better way to do this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your schema, the `include` will not contain the `Artist` relation. It will have to be included from the `Artists_Tracks` relation like this:

```
const result = await prisma.tracks.findMany({
    include: {
      Albums: {
        select: { cover: true },
      },
      Artists_Tracks: { include: { Artists: true } },
    },
})
```

This way you can get the `Artist` for each track present.

Comment: I tried this but I got errors :/ So I thought is there any special way to do in reverse way. include allows us to connect from many to one, but not one to many, isn't it?

Comment: I solved the problem as you said :/ it was because one of my teammate changed DBschema and didn't let us know bout it. It works perfect. Thank you so much.